# Enthought Traits with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, traits, enthought

The question is obvious: is it possible to use both ets Traits and SQLAlchemy for the same class? If no, what an alternative approach could you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to combine them on the same project. Refer to [this project](https://bitbucket.org/fpliger/alchemyui) and a [related mail thread](https://mail.enthought.com/pipermail/enthought-dev/2011-July/029466.html) (dating back to 2011, so things could have improved)

Comment: Second link is dead at the time I am writing this.

Comment: The first link is now also dead :(